# Imageview above action bar android

Tags: android, layout

I am new to android development. In my main activity, I want to hide the action bar and put an ImageView at the very top. However after I hide the action bar, the ImageView won't go to the top as if the action bar is still there. Can anyone explain me how can I place the ImageView at the top.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

tools:context="com.example.bestymobile.MainActivity" 
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/bluelogo" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView2"
    android:gravity= "center" >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/email" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/pass"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/password" />  
    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" 
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Забыли пароль?"
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:layout_marginTop = "20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my layout. So I want the ImageView to be at the very top

Comment: Kim, post your code here, so I could get some idea.

Comment: How are you hiding the actionbar ?

Comment: ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();

Answer (score 0):

First create a  layout for action bar (actionbar.xml);

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center|left" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagehome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then set this layout in your class;

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
```

If you dont want imageview actionbar remove action bar;

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

and set "top" gravity to your imageview